# FD not for shifting gears?

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front

Complete amateur here but I took my 2021 Kona Rove Al650 to the shop today because the FD is not shifting. One of the mechanics told me that the FD on the Kona Rove is only used to adjust the chains and not actually for shifting gears. I clearly have two chainrings. I’ve never seen this system before. What is it called?

Comment: That sounds like some nonsense.

Comment: Try a different shop.

Comment: Perhaps the mechanic meant something else and misspoke, or perhaps you misunderstood, but this seems extremely unlikely. It could be that they mistook the FD for a chain guide on a 1x drivetrain, but that would be an extremely elementary error.

Comment: All I can imagine is that the LBS person thought it was a 1x, or perhaps there was confusion over the Trim positions offered by the left-hand shifter.

Comment: @WeiwenNg exactly, such an elementary error that it is much more likely that there was confusion over the wording of the problem, or reply. Occam's razor seems appropriate

Comment: Unless you're mistaking a bash ring for a chain ring, I'd bet that folks are right and that the shop is mistaken. A picture would clear that up.

Answer (score 4):

They very likely were talking about your front shifter's trim stops.

Your shifter has 3 or 4 positions despite there only being two chainrings. As you shift around in back, the angle that the chain enters the front derailleur changes. This can cause rub. The trim stops exist to change the front derailleur's position enough to eliminate the rub. In other words, when the system is set up correctly, you've got one or two stops in it that shouldn't be moving the chain. (Almost every STI now has 4 but I'm blanking on whether Claris is 3 or 4.)

Answer (score 2):

That's called an **error**.

Two chainrings means you have a front derailleur.  The LBS person is simply incorrect, or possibly something was missed in the speaking/hearing.

Your bike spec is at https://konaworld.com/rove_al_650.cfm and clearly says "Shimano Claris 8 speed" with 34/50 tooth chainrings.

Find a better shop, or search this site for existing questions/answers that are relevant.  Start with https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=front+derailleur+adjust   If none of them match your symptoms, then ask a new question.

Comment: "Error" is a nice word for it.